# How to access id from a nested route in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In my `nuxt` app the nested url looks like this.

```
http://lvh.me:8001/categories/:id/sections/:id

http://lvh.me:8001/categories/40/sections/12
```

How can I access the `categories` id from this page?
`$route.params.id` only returns the `id` of `sections` which is `12`. Is there a way to access the `id` of `categories`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change the parameter name they can't use same name

```
http://lvh.me:8001/categories/:id1/sections/:id2
```